# Return command and variables adb Shell

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell, adb

I am trying to run a shell script in my android board. It has android and I access via adb to the shell. After copying a simple .sh script, I have the following problems for running it.

- Consecutive variables are not recognized. This does not work

```
 PROJ_ON_SYS_PIN='1221'
 echo $PROJ_ON_SYS_PIN> /sys/class/gpio/unexport 
 PROJ_ON_SYS_PIN_2='1222'
 echo $PROJ_ON_SYS_PIN_2> /sys/class/gpio/unexport
```

But this alone works: `echo 1221 > /sys/class/gpio/unexport`

- Enter seems strange behavior: Even refraining using variables this does not work, and is detected as a syntax error. I presume the return (skip line) in not working.

```
  echo 1221> /sys/class/gpio/unexport 
  echo 1223> /sys/class/gpio/unexport
```

Is it related to the shell version?. Because I have been working with bash in linux quite a lot and never experienced this

Comment: Update: when I use && at the end of the line, it works. Is there any explanation for that?

Comment: You are right. It was my first time using windows for this task. I suspected that after a while. I will try to do everything on Linux now.